# What is the correct translation of Exodus 6:3?

Tags: words, jewish-books, torah-study, hebrew, grammar-dikduk

According to BHS, Exodus 6:3 reads:

> וָאֵרָ֗א אֶל־אַבְרָהָ֛ם אֶל־יִצְחָ֥ק וְאֶֽל־יַעֲקֹ֖ב בְּאֵ֣ל שַׁדָּ֑י
>   וּשְׁמִ֣י יְהוָ֔ה לֹ֥א נוֹדַ֖עְתִּי לָהֶֽם׃

This all almost universally translated as something like the following:

> And I appeared to Abraham, to Isaac, and to Jacob as El Shaddai, but
>   by my name YHWH I was not known to them.

However, Francis Andersen, in his book *The Sentence in Biblical Hebrew* argues for a translation that could convey the opposite meaning:

> And I appeared to Abraham, to Isaac, and to Jacob as El Shaddai,
>   and my name is YHWH; did I not make myself known to them?

I do not have access to Andersen's work, so I do not know how he argues for this translation syntactically.

If anyone has access to his work or arguments supporting such a translation, I would be interested in reading them.

Also, is such a translation proposed or mentioned anywhere in ancient Jewish literature?

Comment: The "trup"/cantillation marks indicate that the normal way is correct. There's an "esnachta" under the word "sha-dai" which indicates where to pause and break up the phrase.

Comment: @Binyomin bingo. Please flesh that out as an answer, I'll happily upvote b'n.

Comment: Thanks @Shalom my issue is the OP is asking for sources or arguments in favor of the alternate reading. So I don't know if a source against such a reading could count as an answer.

Comment: Yes, I am asking for arguments in favor of the alternate reading, however the point about cantillation marks is appreciated.

Comment: If this translation were correct, shouldn’t the passuk be הלא נודעתי להם, with the ה השאלה?

Comment: If you notice, "שמי ה' לא נודעתי" means literally "*my name YHWH I didn't make myself known*", it can't mean "*I didn't make my name known*". So the other translation is right literally, especially if we accept that the cantillation marks were added in the Talmudic era. @Binyomin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not correct. Andersen tries to apply the structure within the noncontiguous parallelism (AB-AB) but for this he has made the hebrew LO (not) a positive marker, indicating a rhetorical question.

> A' "I am Yhwh" (v.2).
>
> B'  "And I made myself known to Abraham, to Isaac, and to Jacob as El
>   Shaddai".
>
> A'  "And my name is Yhwh";
>
> B'  "Did I not make myself known to them?"

However, as pointed out by some scholars, he fails to consider that this verse could constitute an *antithetical parallelism* which is, according to professor [Jared Hood](https://jared.hoodfamily.org.au/i-appeared-as-el-shaddai/#_ftnref11), "most likely". Hood also mention the failure to prove Andersen's assertion by saying that his translation violate some known gramatical and syntactical rules, as it lacks the usual Hebrew interrogative particle, and more patently the construction makes the meaning of the verses even more difficult to determine.

He quotes R. W. L. Moberly¹ who has little patience with such a view:

> ‘How on earth would any reader of biblical Hebrew be expected to
>   recognize that lo’ here does not have its familiar negative
>   meaning”?

In his book Moberly goes further:

> It would appear that for Andersen (...) arguments about the Hebrew of
>   Exod. 6:3b are only introduced to buttress a conviction about what the
>   text must mean when read against the context of Genesis. The
>   suggestion that lo’ in 6:3b does not mean “not” needs a far better
>   argument to become remotely plausible.

He then passes to consider the interpretation of Rashi as one of the "most serious option for reinterpreting 6:3". Unfortunately his analysis of Rashi is too long to quote here. But you can check Rashi's commentary by yourself [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9867/showrashi/true#v3).

¹R. W. L. Moberly, [The Old Testament of the Old Testament: Patriarchal Narratives and Mosaic Yahwism](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1579107311) (Minneapolis: Fortress Press, 1992) 57.